# Xcode fails building a static lib for architecture x86_64:

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries, x86-64

I created and built in a separated Xcode project a static library I now added to a second Xcode project for an iOS app. To create the static lib and generate the `.a` file, I followed the instructions in [Creating a Static Library in iOS Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial). I integrated it in the iOS app project and it builds and run for a 32-bits iPhone simulator (iPhone 5 and below), but I get an `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:` when building for an iPhone 6 and above simulator.

In the project and target settings of the static lib project, I see I have the valid architectures set to the Standard... what else should I check? Why this could be happening?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** The script in Target > Buld Phases contains these commands:

```
xcodebuild -target MyLib ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos  BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"
xcodebuild -target MyLib -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator -arch i386 BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"
```

I assume that this will work for all iOS versions in a device (correct me if I'm wrong...), but only for 32-bits simulators. I tried to change the last command to this two:

```
xcodebuild -target MyLib -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator -arch i386 BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"
xcodebuild -target MyLib -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator -arch x86_64 BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"
```

But only last command seems to be the taken one. Then I tried:

```
xcodebuild -target MyLib -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator "ARCHS=i386 x86_64" "VALID_ARCHS=i386 x86_64" BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"
```

But this also doesn't work for both 32 and 64-bit simulators...

**Edit 2:** This is the complete script without my changes for 64 bits:

```
# define output folder environment variable
UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-universal
# Step 1. Build Device and Simulator versions
xcodebuild -target MyLib ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos  BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"
xcodebuild -target MyLib -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator -arch i386 BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"
# make sure the output directory exists
mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"
# Step 2. Create universal binary file using lipo
lipo -create -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a" 
# Last touch. copy the header files. Just for convenience
cp -R "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/include"
"${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/"
```

Comment: Check out this tutorial as well http://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios This is the one I followed to learn how to create frameworks (assuming your goal is to create a .framework from your static library)

Comment: Depending on how you integrate your library into your app target, you might either need to create a fat library with all required architectures or modify the dependent target build settings accordingly.

Comment: @A-Live I tried some things with no success... I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

You can also build for the x86_64 as follows (adding x86_64) :

```
xcodebuild -target MyLib -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk 
iphonesimulator -arch x86_64 -arch i386 BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" 
BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"
```